# How to redirect when route is missing "parts" in asp.net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

Let's say I have a url like this:

```
www.site.com/en/home/list/2010-09-30
```

The "en" is for English, and I want to make sure there is always a language token set in the url. If a user enters `www.site.com/home/list/2010-09-30` I want it to redirect them to `www.site.com/en/home/list/2010-09-30` (where en is the default language).

How is this best accomplished in asp.net MVC (version if that matters)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would probably best be handled in a custom HttpModule.  I'm sure you already know, but just in case, you can default the route value "en" in your route declarations as well.  It won't redirect the page but the culture will always be set in code if it's not present in the URL.

```
context.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { culture = "en", action = "Index" });
```

Comment: Do you have an example of how this would be handled in the custom HttpModule? I'd create the HttpModule as described here: http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/909/custom-http-module/ but since I've never built one before, not quite sure how to check for language, does it have access to the route?

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to have a wildcard route (This should be at the bottom of your global.asax file):

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "WildCard",
                "{*url}",
                new { controller = "Main", action = "EnglishDefault" }
            );
```

Then your action would be:

```
public ActionResult EnglishDefault (string url)
{
   return Redirect("/en/" + url);
}
```

Comment: Would wildcard route catch the difference between the url's I described? Seems like it wouldn't reach the wildcard route... I'll play with the routes a bit. Thanks for the idea.

Comment: @Chad - I would make sure I had routes defined above this wildcard route to handle the properly formatted URL's. This route would go at the bottom of your route table and be used as a catch all to then redirct to the correct format.